# Get first row, first column value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure (that I can't modify) that returns a single value via a `SELECT` at the end of the procedure. I need to use that value in my own procedure. How can I get that value?

Here is an example of the procedure I am calling that I can not modify:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_poorlywritten] (
....
)
BEGIN
    ....
    SELECT @lastkey;
    RETURN (0);
END
```

And here is what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work because this gets the return value, and what I need is that `SELECT` value:

```
exec @next_key = SP_poorlywritten 'tablename',1;
```

How can I store the first column, first row value from a store procedure?

Comment: `RETURN` is for error/status, it is [not meant for data](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output) (which is why it only supports `int` - if your column were `bigint` or any non-integer data type, you wouldn't be able to use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify the existing stored procedure, you will not be able to utilize the `RETURN` as you would like to.

An alternative may be to insert the output of the procedure's select statement into a temp table, and then query that directly to populate a variable.

That would look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
   LastKey INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC [dbo].[SP_poorlywritten]
```

See this existing [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table) for more details on how you might accomplish this.

As Aaron Bertrand pointed out, `RETURN` is for error/status. If you were able to modify the stored procedure, you would want to utilize an output parameter instead of `RETURN`. This is how you would do that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name
    @Output int OUTPUT
AS
    <do some stuff>

    SET @Output = <some_value>
GO

DECLARE @Output int

EXEC proc_name @Output = @Output
```